# How do I create an arbitrary number of UILabel Objects, each with a PanGestureRecognizer.

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to create an iPad app in which the user can create state models to describe the dynamic properties of ion channels. The first goal I need to accomplish is to allow for the user to create any arbitrary number of open or closed states, each to be represented by a UILabel object. Ideally, I would like to allow the user to be able to move any of these labels around freely after they have been created. In trying to implement this design, I have run across some issues. I have searched all over for similar problems, but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I created two UIButtons, one which creates a new, green UILabel called openState, and one which creates a new, red UILabel called closedState. After either of these states are created by clicking the corresponding button, a pan gesture recognizer is added to the label which specifies an action, move, that will allow the user to move the label anywhere in the view they wish.

This works if I create one label. I can move it around freely. However, if I create another one after that, the new one is free to be moved, but the previous one loses that ability. How can I create gesture recognizers for each label that will stay with them permanently? I thought I should perhaps make an NSMutableDictionary to hold all the different gesture recognizers, and give them different key names. I recognize now that the gesture recognizer on previous states is failing because it is being declared under the same name _panGestureRecognizer each time createNewClosedState or createNewOpenState is called.

I've posted the entire source code below. Many of the commented out lines are attempts I had previously made at fixing the problem.

If anyone could shed any light on this problem, I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm pretty new to Objective-C and programming in general. This is my first big project, and I'm sure I'm making some easy mistake resulting from my misunderstanding of some concept.

Thanks!

```
****ViewController.h****
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *createClosedStateButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *createOpenStateButton;



//@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *stateLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRec;



@end



**ViewController.m**
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()
{
    int stateCount;
    int numClosedStates;
    int numOpenStates;

    NSMutableDictionary *stateDictionary;
    NSMutableDictionary *gestureRecognizers;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    stateCount = 0;
    numClosedStates = 0;
    numOpenStates = 0;

    stateDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    gestureRecognizers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)createNewClosedState:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Closed State Button was clicked.");

    //Increase count of closed states
    numClosedStates++;


    //Create new label object for the new closed state.
    UIView *stateLabel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.createClosedStateButton.frame.origin.x, self.createClosedStateButton.frame.origin.y + 100, 50, 50)];

    _panGestureRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move: forView:)];



    //_stateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"C%i", numClosedStates];

    //center text and set background color.
   // _stateLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    stateLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    //Add gesture recognizer to the state label.
    [stateLabel addGestureRecognizer:_panGestureRec];

    //Add state view to stateDictionary.
    //NSString *stateIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Closed State %i", numClosedStates];
    //[stateDictionary setObject:stateLabel forKey:stateIdentifier];
    //[gestureRecognizers setObject:_panGestureRec forKey:stateIdentifier];

    //add label to view.
    [self.view addSubview:stateLabel];


    //Increase total state count by one.
    stateCount++;
    NSLog(@"State count is %i", stateCount);
}

-(IBAction)createNewOpenState:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Open State Button was clicked.");

    //Increase amount of open states.
    numOpenStates++;

    //Create new label object for new open state.
    UIView *stateLabel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.createClosedStateButton.frame.origin.x, self.createClosedStateButton.frame.origin.y + 100, 50, 50)];


    //_stateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"O%i", numOpenStates];

    _panGestureRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move: forView:)];



    //center text and set background color.
    //_stateLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter
    stateLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    //Add gesture recognizer to the state label.
    [stateLabel addGestureRecognizer:_panGestureRec];

    //Add state view to stateDictionary.
    //NSString *stateIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Open State %i", numOpenStates];
    //[stateDictionary setObject:stateLabel forKey:stateIdentifier];
    //[gestureRecognizers setObject:_panGestureRec forKey:stateIdentifier];

    //add label to view.
    [self.view addSubview:stateLabel];


    //Increase total state count by one.
    stateCount++;
    NSLog(@"State count is %i", stateCount);

}

-(void)move:(id)sender forView:(UIView *)stateLabel
{


    if (_panGestureRec.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        // Start of the gesture.
        // You could remove any layout constraints that interfere
        // with changing of the position of the content view.
    }
    else if (_panGestureRec.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        // Calculate new center of the view based on the gesture recognizer's
        // translation.
        CGPoint newCenter = stateLabel.center;
        newCenter.x += [_panGestureRec translationInView:self.view].x;
        newCenter.y += [_panGestureRec translationInView:self.view].y;

        // Set the new center of the view.
        stateLabel.center = newCenter;

        // Reset the translation of the recognizer.
        [_panGestureRec setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
    }
    else if (_panGestureRec.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        // Dragging has ended.
        // You could add layout constraints back to the content view here.
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: If you put this on github as a project that I can download and immediately run, it would make it easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your action method. The action method for a pan gesture recognizer should have just one parameter, which is the recognizer itself (it should be typed to UIPanGestureRecognizer). You can get the view it's attached to with sender.view. You don't need to keep a dictionary of the recognizers, since each view has its own.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with the action method. Modified it to be an IBAction method with only the recognizer as the parameter. Thanks for your help!